# How can I use URL Rewriting Middleware asp core 2.2?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, iis-express

I have two differents asp mvc applications one legacy in mvc 5 and the other one in asp net core mvc I want to have one end point such as "/OLD" in asp new core in order to call legacy code in other host. All of this must work at the same time on IIS Express since I'm developing in asp core project. How can I bind legacy project in the asp core project like a one unique domain. I was traying use Rewriting Middleware but I can't manage to make it work without redirects.

```
app.UseRewriter(new RewriteOptions().AddRewrite("/old","localhost:2323",true));//localhost:2323 is legacy project hosted in local IIS.
```

Why this don't call localhost:2323? I need another rule?

Comment: It is kind of late to perform such on ASP.NET Core. Learn IIS URL Rewrite module and carry out the rewriting on IIS level.

Answer (score 0):

Rewriting middleware does not "execute" anything. It just rewrites current URL so other parts of app think request arrived in "rewritten" form.

If specific handler is located in *other* application - rewriting URL inside current application has no effect. You should either redirect user to old application, or write your own middleware that will execute request to other app and return result from it behalf.